# swprintf declaration mismatch

Tags: c++, c, mingw

I use MinGW g++ compiler on Windows (gcc version 4.8.1) and I am confused with swprintf declaration

According to [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cwchar/swprintf/) it should be

```
int swprintf (wchar_t* ws, size_t len, const wchar_t* format, ...);
```

However when I use

```
swprintf(my_ws, 32, L"hello");
```

I get error

```
initializing argument 2 of 'int swprintf(wchar_t*, const wchar_t*, ...)' [-fpermissive]
```

Looks like `size_t len` is not in the declaration. Is the reference wrong, did I miss something or is there some story behind that?

Comment: What mingw version are you using?

Comment: The gcc version is 4.8.1

Comment: Try defining `USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` in the compiler switches  (e.g. `-DUSE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`)

Comment: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.29.2.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a C library that is not compliant with the C99 Standard.

MinGW is a port of `gcc` that uses the Microsoft C runtime library.

Microsoft had its own version of `swprintf` with a different prototype before it was standardized into C99. It is a very old C library with a lot of C99 incompatibilities, for example I don't think its `printf` supports `%zu` for `size_t`...

You should upgrade to a more recent version of MinGW if they use a more recent runtime.  If not, you are going to have to use the old prototype, and live with these obsolete APIs.

Comment: `mingw` is not visual studio though? Doesnt mingw use `gcc/g++`?

Comment: I understand that, but MinGW uses the Microsoft C library that comes with their compiler.

Comment: `mingw` uses the Visual C++ runtime for its library implementation... a very OLD msvcrt.dll that has the old non-standard parameters.  (Well, actually msvcrt.dll isn't so old, but it is backward compatible with the MSVC 6.0 one, so...)

Comment: In particular, a new Visual Studio that comes with msvc140.dll (or whatever the name is) won't have any effect on mingw, which continues to use msvcrt.dll

Comment: @BenVoigt: you are correct, I updated my answer.  Hopefully MinGW will eventually support a more recent C runtime, as Microsoft seems to have finally moved closer to C99 .

Comment: If msvcrt.dll is used, does it mean that the code is not portable??

Comment: @JanTuroň: I'm afraid you are correct, the code is not portable to another environment to this regard.  Do you program to the Windows API or only using Standard C APIs or possibly POSIX.  If you do not target Windows specifically, you should install `cygwin`.  It comes with a more recent C runtime.

Comment: All the more reason to use MinGW-w64, instead of the old abandonware mingw

Comment: @M.M: Ok, so [mingw-w64 doesn't believe in using msvcrt.dll](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/The%20case%20against%20msvcrt.dll/)  What library does it use?

Comment: @BenVoigt I think it still uses msvcrt.dll for most functions but provides its own C99-compliant versions of swprintf, etc.